# C++ Fast and Efficient way to perform bit_count and AND operation on 40 byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, bit-manipulation, bitcount

In my project I need to AND two binary array of size 40 bytes(320 bits) and then compute set bit count in C++. I found some algorithms to do this but I want to know what is the fastest way of implementing it in c++. I mean what c++ data type would be proper?(unsinged char*,unsigned int 32,u_int64,...). I know many algorithms are compatible with 32bit integer although my array size is 40 bytes .

what about the algorithms described in this link:
[Fast Bit Counting Techniques](http://bajeed.blogspot.com/2008/09/bit-counting-techniques.html) which one is faster?

Is const type better or there is no difference?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, do you only want the bit_count of the AND result, and don't need the AND result itself, or do you need both?

Comment: Is this platform-specific or does it need to be portable ?

Comment: If its possible, you can use `std::bitset`....

Comment: I don't need AND result.just bit count of AND

Comment: I'm using Qt.I prefer the algorithm to be compatible for Android platforms too. But my first priority is Qt under Windows

Comment: Why do you care? I ask because a anding two 40 byte arrays and counting the bits on a gigahertz processor is going to be trivial.  We are talking about memory sizes that are going to fit into cache and a couple hundred clock cycles at worst.  What would be the fastest method is going to be highly platform and compiler dependent while buying you next to nothing compared to the naive implementation.  Who cares.... write code that is clear and concise.

Comment: I want to perform it for about 10000 times. So it matters!

Comment: @user1624507 - For whatever it is worth to you, on my laptop PC, using `std::bitset<320>` as I have outlined in my answer, I can do 10,000,000 iterations in 4 seconds. I suppose 10,000 iterations takes .004 seconds.

Comment: OH MY GOD! I'm looking for significantly faster performance. 4 mili second is disaster for me

Comment: It would help if you stated what you performance requirement actually is - i.e. how many ns or CPU clocks per iteration do you actually *need* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a version that goes through the array with 4 bytes at once, requiring 10 iterations:

```
uint32_t *arr1_int = (uint32_t*) arr1;
uint32_t *arr2_int = (uint32_t*) arr2;
int i;
int bits_set = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    uint32_t v = arr1_int[i] & arr2_int[i];

    /* http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel */
    v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);                   
    v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);    
    bits_set += ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

You can do this a lot faster with a modern CPU, using compiler intrinsics. For example on a 64 bit CPU with Visual C++:

```
#include <intrin.h>

__int64 *arr1_int = (__int64*) arr1;
__int64 *arr2_int = (__int64*) arr2;
int bits_set = 0;

/* 40 / 8 bytes == 5 iterations */
bits_set += __popcnt64(*arr1_int++ & *arr2_int++);
bits_set += __popcnt64(*arr1_int++ & *arr2_int++);
bits_set += __popcnt64(*arr1_int++ & *arr2_int++);
bits_set += __popcnt64(*arr1_int++ & *arr2_int++);
bits_set += __popcnt64(*arr1_int++ & *arr2_int++);
```

But this is all with performance in mind, if you simply want some readable code that works definitely go with what Rob suggested.

Comment: @MarkRansom: scroll down a bit.

Comment: I would add that modern means nehelem for intel cpus and bulldozer for amd cpus, so the intrinsic version rises the bar for the pretty high.

Comment: There's a nice way to emulate popcnt with just SSSE3, it's normally slightly faster than native popcnt (weird, but true) but in this case there would be some padding, so who knows. Worth a try IMO. And it would run on Core2, which this doesn't.

Comment: The lookup table idea, but for 4 bits. Split the input into high and low nibbles, then `pshufb` them with the table.

Answer (score 6):

> I mean what c++ data type would be proper?

`std::bitset<320>`.

Any algorithm you come up with should be compared in speed and convenience to this one:

```
std::bitset<320> first;
std::bitset<320> other;

// twiddle bits here ...

std::bitset<320> and_result(first & other);
std::size_t number_of_bits(and_result.count());
```

If the alternatives don't go significantly faster, just use code like the above. It will clearly express your intent, and will avoid maintenance headaches later on.

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like this should be plenty fast enough:

```
const uint8_t LUT[256] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, ..., 8 }; // pop count LUT for bytes

int count_bits(const uint8_t *a1, const uint8_t *a2, int n)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        count += LUT[a1[i] & a2[i]];
    }
    return count;
}
```

The are three loads and two ALU operations per byte, i.e. 120 loads and 80 ALU ops for your 40 byte use case.

Try it, profile it, and if it's not fast enough then you can look at more complex solutions that might be faster.

Comment: Do you believe const type is faster or there is no difference? And can you little explain your code?

Comment: With most compilers `const` probably won't make any difference in the above case, but it's still good practice. As for explaining the code, is there something in particular that is not clear?

Comment: I'm wondering if you could explain what is n and how you get the LUT?

Comment: `n` is just the number of bytes - for your particular use case you would be passing 40 for n, but the routine can obviously be used for any size of array. The LUT, as the comment next to it says, is a population count look-up table, so each entry is the population count for the corresponding 8 bit value, hence 0 = 0, 1 = 1, 2 = 1, 3 = 2, 4 = 1, 5 = 2, 6 = 2, 7 = 3, ... all the way up to 255 = 8.