# Sum reduction of binary sequence

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

Consider a binary sequence:

11000111

I have to find sum of this series (actually in parallel)

Sum =1+1+0+0+0+1+1+1= 5

This is a waste of resource as why invest time in adding 0s?

Is there any clever way to sum this sequence so I can avoid unnecessary additions?

Comment: see [Counting bits set](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)

Comment: Say what ? This is a really bizarre definition of reduction of a binary sequence. It's plain summation. And what parallel paradigm you are using ? Arguably, simplest would be [OpenMP + reduction + for loop](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION).

Answer (score 2):

Operate at the byte level rather than the bit level. [Use a small LUT to convert a byte to a population count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630743/253056). That way you're only doing one lookup and one add per 8 bits. Unless your data is likely to be *very* sparse this should be quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on how you store your bitset.
If it's an array, then you can't do more than a plain for. If you want to do this in parallel, just split the array in chunks and process them concurrently.

If we are talking about a bitset (storing the bits in a native (32/64-bit) integer type), then the simplest way to count bits would be this one:

```
int bitset;
int s = 0;
for (; bitset; s++)
    bitset &= bitset-1;
```

This removes the last bit of 1 at every step, so you have O(s).

Of course, you can combine these two methods if you need more than 32/64 bits

Answer (score 0):

I dunno why people are answering, not even looking into link from the 1st comment to the question. You can easily make it under `O(size_of_bitset)`. At lewast when it comes to constant factor.

You could use this method (found in [link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) by J.F. Sebastian):

```
inline int count_bits(int num){
int sum = 0;
for (; bitset; sum++) bitset &= bitset-1;
return sum;
}

int main (void){
  int array[N];
  int total_sum = 0;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:total_sum)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < N, i++){
     total_sum += count_bits(array[i]);
  }
}
```

This will count number of bits in memory range of `array` in parallel. The inline is important to avoid unnecessary copying, also the compiler should optimize it much better.

You can swap the `count_bits` with anything better that counts bits in an integer to get faster if you find anything. This version has complexity of `O(bits_set)` (not size of the bit set!).

Invoking the parallel construct will introduce quite a lot of overhead compared to a single summation that it does need to be quite large to compensate.

The parallelism is done via OpenMP. The partial sum of each thread is summed at the end of the parallel loop and stored in `total_sum`. Note the `total_sum` will be private inside the loop for each thread [`reduction`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#REDUCTION) due to reduction clause.

You could alter the code to make it count bits set in arbitrary memory region but it is quite important for it to be memory aligned when you perform operations on such low level.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, it would be wasteful to try to handle the zeros specially. As @bdares said, addition is really cheap. At a minimum, you'll need to execute N instructions to sum up the an N-bit sequence, that would be if you unconditionally sum ever bit. If you add a test to see whether the bit is a 0 or 1, that's another instruction that needs to be executed for each bit. Even if there's no branch penalty, you're executing minimum 1 instruction for every bit (the conditional test), and then you're also executing the original instruction (the add) for any bits that are equal to 1. So even without branch penalty, this takes more time to execute.

@bdares mentions that the compiler will optimize out the branches, but that's only if the value of each bit is known at compile time, and if you know the values of the bits at compile time, you should just add them up yourself in advance.

There might be some cute things you can do with bit twiddling. For instance, if you take the bits two at a time you're adding up values of 0, 1, 2, or 3, and only have half as many additions to do. There *may* by something you can then do with the result to convert it into the value you want, but I haven't actually thought about how to do that.